# Can't find crystalReportViewer.ReportSource

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition and I've installed  the Beta 2 release of SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010. Everything works fine but when I try to set the ReportSource property for the crystalReportViewer I can't find it. Is there any other way to bind a crystal report to CrystalReportViewer?  This is my source:

```
        var cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load("~/CrystalReports/DateToDateReport.rpt");

        new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo;
        var crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

        var crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue {Value = dtpFromDate.Value};

        ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["fromDate"];
        ParameterValues crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

        crParameterValues.Clear();
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = dtpToDate.Value;
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["toDate"];
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "ServerName";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Database";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "Username";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "Password";

        var crTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (Table crTable in crTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set .NET FRAMEWORK 4.0 --> 3.5

Answer (score 1):

It's actually `crystalReportViewer1.**ViewerCore**.ReportSource = cryRpt;1

Comment: Only when using WPF. Win forms uses crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource